# As a recruiter, what do you look for in a motivation or cover letter?

Tags: recruitment, cover-letter

As a recruiter what information do you try to find in a motivation letter? I am mainly concerned with fields in STEM, however, opinion from other fields is also welcome.

Comment: I would ask to clarify what a "motivation letter" is exactly? I have never heard of this term before. A cover letter is something different, I would expect, such that it just gives a more broad overview of your skills, experiences, and value you would bring to the company/role. It's 50:50 if someone _actually ever reads it_ versus running it through software.

Comment: Voting to close because it's asking for opinions.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica Anything could be interpreted as asking for opinions as many things are not as strict as 2+2=4.
Any answer given on this site section is an opinion! There is no grand theory of what-to-do-in-a-work-place that people can study and test. People here give their opinion and the opinion which has more supporter gets more vote.

Answer (score 10):

The role of the cover letter is often misunderstood but it is actually straight forward

1. The job description is about the role (same for all candidates)
2. Your resume is about you (same for all jobs you apply for)
3. The cover letter connects the two, it's specific to this combination of job and yourself

Good things to cover

1. How you stack up against the listed requirements (one by one) based on your resume and other info
2. Demonstrate that you did some homework, i.e. researched the company and the specific job.
3. Explain why the job/role/company is good for you and how it fits into your career and life choices
4. Explain why you are good for the job/role/company. What do you bring to the party and why is it a good idea for them to hire you.

The goal of the cover the letter is to show that this is an intentional, considered, and purposeful application and not some random scattershot as unfortunately 90%+ of all applications are these days. Some tips:

- Keep it short, cover what you need to cover efficiently and concisely. Less is more here.
- The requirements assessment part is important and I found that an actual table (column 1: requirements, column 2: your fit) works well. Here is why: in most larger companies resumes are typically scanned first by HR staffers that know very little about the actual role. Their job is to go through the requirement list and do a rough check to weed out the obvious non-fits. If you provide them with a well organized requirements/fit list you save them a lot of work and they will love you for it.
- Make sure that you write something that's specific to the job and the
  company. If your letter would be equally applicable to a different job at a different company you are doing it wrong.
- Makes sure you demonstrate some actual homework. Reference a website
  or article or some public domain information that shows that you put
  some work into this.

Answer (score 0):

There are no specific things to look for. You should be considering what the employer wants, and see if that is reflected in the letter through the persons ability to express themselves and if that person would match the company likewise.

If company x wants a STEM employee that is passionate in AI, you look through cover letters where a person mentions that, or at least hints at that knowledge or interest and they move to the follow up pile.

Humans are weird things and there shouldn’t be a check list of what to watch out for when searching through them, rather a sound empathetic understanding of what the employer and employee want, if their ‘personalities’ match and if both will be happy with each other.

If I forced you to sit down and write a 10 page essay in a professional way about yourself right this second, you’d likely falter. However the things you would probably mention would be clues enough to for a attentive reader to notice, and want to know more.

Not everyone is great at writing, read letters, see if they fit, follow up with a phone call, get specific, find out if that person is really good at STEM but not great at writing about themselves.